# What are some good physics websites for learning in general?

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

As a 17-year-old who is interested in physics and especially in the laws of the universe, what are some good websites that are clear explanations and straight to the point?

Comment: I don't think we accept list questions at Physics.SE.

Comment: @bobie note that the [tag:specific-reference] tag is entirely inappropriate for this question